# Loading multiple components to router-outlet from same path Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm using Angular 4.
I want to use a shell with 2 named router-outlets (named "search" & "table").
When the path is '/users' , I want to load user-search component to the search outlet and the user-table component to the "table" outlet, without changing the path.

I'm currently bypassing the problem by having only one router-outlet that load the child components. The problem is, that I want it to repeat in all the pages of the application and I don't like the want to repeat the boiler plat in each new page